# Validation of Zoom Webhook Endpoint with Google Apps Script Fails

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks, verification, zoom-sdk

I am having trouble validating my endpoint, which is a Google Apps Script.

Endpoint Google Apps Script code

```
function doPost(e) {

  const requestMessage = e.postData.contents;
  const requestJSON = JSON.parse(requestMessage)
  const pT = requestJSON.payload.plainToken
  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(pT, sT, Utilities.Charset.US_ASCII);
  var hexString = signature
    .map(function (byte) {
      // Convert from 2's compliment
      var v = (byte < 0) ? 256 + byte : byte;

      // Convert byte to hexadecimal
      return ("0" + v.toString(16)).slice(-2);
    })
    .join("");

  const response = {
    plainToken: pT,
    encryptedToken: hexString
  }

  return JSON.stringify(response)
}
```

The validation fails, although the encrypted token appears to be correct. [The instructions](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/webhook-reference/#validate-your-webhook-endpoint) state that I should reply with status 200 and a JSON with the plainToken and encryptedToken, and it was my understanding that GAS basically always returns with status 200.

Thank you very much.

I tried using the node.js "response", but this is not available.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, when the value of `response` is the valid value, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
return JSON.stringify(response)
```

#### To:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

or

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response));
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [Class ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
It did not work.
I checked if the response is valid (from the standpoint of the plainToken and encryptedToken) based on an online service and it was correct.

Comment: @matskohe Thank you for replying. About `It did not work.`, I apologize for the inconvenience. From `I checked if the response is valid (from the standpoint of the plainToken and encryptedToken) based on an online service and it was correct.`, I understood that your value of `response` is correct. In this case, when you reflected your latest modified script to Web Apps, what result will you obtain? From your reply, I'm worried about it.

Comment: @matskohe And also, in this case, please test the following flow. 1. Desable the webhook. 2. Enable the webhook again. 3. Test the modified script again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and advice and sorry for my late reply. I followed the flow, but it did not work. I followed [Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43), but it did not work either.

Comment: Regarding your question, `when you reflected your latest modified script to Web Apps, what result will you obtain?` , Zoom app page verification says `URL validation failed. Try again later`. screen shot is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gFCt3DHIkgK9B-6HkLWDtBXFTn5tmtS8/view?usp=sharing). I wonder if it is good that I use curl command to send a http POST request like a webhook to the endpoint to check the response from the endpoint. What do you think about it?

Comment: @matskohe Thank you for replying. About `I wonder if it is good that I use curl command to send a http POST request like a webhook to the endpoint to check the response from the endpoint. What do you think about it?`, what result did you obtain?

Comment: I put my curl command(POST request) and the response below cuz it was too long to put here all.

Comment: @matskohe Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, you are posting a comment as an answer. I apologize for this. Please remove it. And, about your curl command, I think that your curl command is not correct. Please test `curl -L -d '{"payload":{"plainToken":"OOOOOOOOOOOO"},"event_ts":1654503849680,"event":"endpoint.url_validation"}' https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec`.

Comment: I gave up verifying only by gas. I made a node.js server, and it has worked.

Comment: @matskohe Thank you for replying. About `I gave up verifying only by gas. I made a node.js server, and it has worked.`, I understood it. But, I think that this answer to your question might be useful for other users. So, I would like to leave my answer.